# How can I set an activity depending on a parameter on Android application?

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to figure out how to go to different activity depending on some parameter.

Please help me... The code below is my code though it doesn't work.

```
                            String className;
                            if (Parameter == 0) {
                                className = "class.A." + Parameter + "Activity.class";
                            } else if (Parameter == 1) {
                                className = "class.B." + Parameter + "Activity.class";
                            }
                            //activityClass = (Cast className to Class);

                            Intent intent = new Intent(ExampleActivity.this, activityClass);
                            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                            startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to code something like this. hope it will help you.

```
 Intent intent=null;
 if (Parameter == 0) {
          intent=new Intent(ExampleActivity.this,yourclass);
 } else if (Parameter == 1) {
          intent=new Intent(ExampleActivity.this,yourclass);
 }
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to change the class name depending on the parameter... like how I wrote

Comment: you can define your class in if condition.like if (Parameter == 0) {
          intent=new Intent(ExampleActivity.this,ClassA.class);
 }else if (Parameter == 1) {
          intent=new Intent(ExampleActivity.this,CalssB.class);
 }

Comment: It has "Parameter" itself in the class name in the string variable

Comment: actually i didn't get you. explain in brief what you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Class className;
if (Parameter == 0) {
           className = Activity1.class;
} else  {
           className = Activity2.class;
}


Intent intent = new Intent(ExampleActivity.this, className );
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to change the class name depending on the parameter... like how I wrote

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I got you, but you can try to use Class.forName() function. Your code would look like this:

```
String className;
if (Parameter == 0) {  
    className = "class.A." + Parameter + "Activity";
} else if (Parameter == 1) {
    className = "class.B." + Parameter + "Activity";
}

Class activityClass = Class.forName(className);

Intent intent = new Intent(ExampleActivity.this, activityClass);
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
startActivity(intent);
```

Remember that you have to skip ".class" extenstion in your className String.

Comment: This is what I wanted! :D Thank you!